# Confusing reputation history navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, reputation-history

When browsing the 1st page of reputation history, the button at the bottom says `next`.

But really, page 2 shows *older* reputation history.

[image: rep history page nav]

This should be changed to say `older` to prevent confusion.  And vice versa, when linking back to page 1, the button should say `newer`.

Better yet, make the history a continuous list that has a `Load More` button at the end of a "section," similar to YouTube.

Comment: No repro, page 2 showing older events, just as it should. Nothing to fix or change here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I mean to change the text of the button to "previous" **because** page 2 shows older events.  Pressing "next" to view older events isn't logical.

Comment: This is confusing. You are given a book, do you turn it over to see a new, next or previous page? It doesn't matter that the book is a ledger with entries sorted from most recent to oldest.

Comment: @DeerHunter Fair point.  How about buttons that say "newer" and "older" instead?  Pretty sure you can't confuse _that_.

Comment: This is just wrong. The order of the pages is by the time of the reputation events, descending.

Answer (score -2):

The sort order is obvious, and the "<kbd>next</kbd>" button indicates "next page in pagination" ***not*** "next moment in history".

I understand the change, and I feel it would be more fitting; however, because the existing format is intuitive in its own right, it might be too insignificant a change to warrant tearing SE apart.

I'm always hoping they'll improve the site with minor changes that we can believe in, also, but I guess the gears turn slow.

Comment: For example, if you were reading a book with archival data, and the first page started in December 2015 and went backwards to January 2015, the reader would likely always expect the `next page` to start at the previous year in December, and so-on until the book ended.  And when you look at a picture album, the most recent images are on the first page, and the older images are on the `next page`.